# proper layout folder title for 7 inch tablet

Tags: java, android, layout, tablet

I am trying to target 7 inch tablets most specifically the 2013 nexus 7. As suggested by http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts I made folders called layout-sw600dp and layout-xlarge, but unfortunately neither of those worked. What is the most preferred way to name the folder to make a layout for 7 inch tablets?

Comment: Please explain what "neither of those worked" means. `layout-xlarge` would be for 10" tablets, so a Nexus 7 would not use that resource.

Comment: Meaning that the app crashes when I load the app on a nexus 7 because there are no resources for it with those 2 folder titles I previously tried.

Comment: You should always have a default folder for all `resources`. For the `layout` folder, for instance, you should have a folder named `layout` with no qualifiers so nothing that fits in other categories has a `layout` for each `Activity`. Just like for `strings` you will have the default besides any extra languages you may want to support.